OidcUserService.setAccessibleScopes deprecated
OidcUserService.setAccessibleScopes is depreacted.
We are creating the OidcUserService like this:
final OidcUserService oidcUserService = new OidcUserService();
    oidcUserService.setOauth2UserService(userService);
    oidcUserService.setAccessibleScopes(
        Set.of(
            OidcScopes.PROFILE,
            OidcScopes.EMAIL,
            OidcScopes.ADDRESS,
            OidcScopes.PHONE,
            OidcScopes.OPENID));
    return oidcUserService;

The deprecated hint is to use .setRetrieveUserInfo(). But how?
I've tried this:
oidcUserService.setRetrieveUserInfo(oidcUserRequest -> oidcUserRequest.getClientRegistration().getScopes().addAll(Set.of(
            OidcScopes.PROFILE,
            OidcScopes.EMAIL,
            OidcScopes.ADDRESS,
            OidcScopes.PHONE,
            OidcScopes.OPENID)));

but scopes is a UnmodefiableCollection.
Thanks for your replies.

You are misinterpreting the use of setAccessibleScopes. Those are the scopes that are allowed, you don't need to set them in the setRetrieveUserInfo instead you should check the passed in in scopes if it contains one of (or all of) the scopes. You don't set them.

The default implementation checks the accessibleScopes which is something you should now do yourselves as that is more flexible. The setRetrieveUserInfo accepts a Predicate which is just for testing something (a request comes in a boolean comes out).
What you should write is something like this.

private boolean customShouldRetrieveUserInfo(OidcUserRequest userRequest) {
  var final scopes = Set.of(OidcScopes.PROFILE,
            OidcScopes.EMAIL,
            OidcScopes.ADDRESS,
            OidcScopes.PHONE,
            OidcScopes.OPENID);
    ProviderDetails providerDetails = userRequest.getClientRegistration().getProviderDetails();
    if (!StringUtils.hasLength(providerDetails.getUserInfoEndpoint().getUri())) {
        return false;
    }

    if (AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE
        .equals(userRequest.getClientRegistration().getAuthorizationGrantType())) {
        return this.accessibleScopes.isEmpty()
                || CollectionUtils.isEmpty(userRequest.getAccessToken().getScopes())
                || CollectionUtils.containsAny(userRequest.getAccessToken().getScopes(), scopes);
    }
    return false;
}

This is a method you can use as the predicate (inspired by the original method).
final OidcUserService oidcUserService = new OidcUserService();
    oidcUserService.setOauth2UserService(userService);
    oidcUserService.setRetrieveUserInfo(this::customShouldRetrieveUserInfo);
    return oidcUserService;

Something like this.
